# create simple currency converter exchange live rate in android

Tags: android, currency

long time ago I try to create currency converter for android that has live exchange rate from webservice. but I can't, can anyone give me how to receive rate from webservice? and more than this please give me simple currency converter exchange live rate project.

Comment: You would have to use REST or SOAP to call the webservice. The return will most probably be in XML which you would have to parse.Personally the way I did it was to use soap ui and generate the java code for it and then call it from my program.This way I did not have to add any external dependency to my file.

Comment: (http://www.firstamong.com/building-android-currency-converter/) I try to build simple currency converter via link above but nothing happen. can you test this project and tell me what wrong in this project. if possibly give me a successful project. thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check [this](http://code.google.com/p/android-currency-converter/source/browse/trunk/src/com/hykwok/CurrencyConverter/?r=10) for currency conversion of more than 15 countries

Answer (score 1):

This [tutorial](http://www.appsrox.com/android/tutorials/forexwiz/) not only covers currency conversion in Android but also historical exchange rates using chart.